# Открыть .pyc файл с помощью C#

Tags: c#, python-3.x, процесс

У меня есть проект на **C#**, но некоторые его части написанны **python 3.5**. Я хочу, чтобы при запуске моего **C#** проекта, автоматически запускался и моя **python**  программа. С помощью [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org), я превратил свой **.py** файл в **.pyc**. Вот способы которыми я способал открыть файл с помощью **C#**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Я знаю, что File.Open() открывает FileStream для чтения и записи. Попробовал это от безысходности
    File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Этот вариант просто не сработал, запускалась пустая консоль и ничего не происходило (я точно уверен что **.pyc** не запустился, ибо он должен был написать *Hello World!* в определённый текстовый файл, чего он не сделал)

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process prc = new Process();
    prc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = filepath;
    prc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath);
    prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

    prc.Start();
}
```

Этот вариант выдал [Win32Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHCWin32);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) с информацией:

> Указанный исполняемый файл не является действительным

P.S При преобразовании из **.py** в **.pyc**, pyinstalller также создал **.exe** файл с именем моего **python** скрипта, но он (в отличие от файлов **.py** и **.pyc**), выдает `Error` (аналог `Exception` на **python**) сразу при запуске (даже если запуск из среды)

---

**UPD**: Попробовал сделать **.pyc** файл аргументом к **.exe** файлу, получился такой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to start process 'File_Bot.exe'...");

    Process prc = new Process();
    prc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    prc.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
    prc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exePath);
    prc.StartInfo.Arguments = pycPath;
    prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

    prc.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Process {0}.exe started!", prc.ProcessName);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Оба сообщения на консоль выводятся, но процесс не делает то, что должен (хотя **.py** файл на котором он основам делает). Процесс даже не появляется в диспетчере задач...

Также попробовал запустить **.exe** из консоли, выдал Stack Trace который не выдается при запуске **.py** файла

Comment: Если запустить из среды Ваш .exe файл - он тоже выдаст error?

Comment: @eblomyac Да, причем файл сразу же закрывается, даже не могу прочитать Traceback

Comment: Можно предположить что в скрипте ошибка. Попробуйте добавить в скрипт хоть какой-нибудь лог\вывод ошибки. С питоном не знаком, но мне кажется что можно выполнить .py и .pyc подав их как аргумент для исполняемого файла питона, примерно вот так: C:\python\python.exe -s script.pyc .

Comment: Чтобы консоль не закрывалась сразу - самый простой способ без изменения c# кода - запустите exe файл через cmd. Shift+ПКМ в папке с exe, открыть окно команд, и там `exeName.exe`. Тогда стектрейс можно будет прочитать.

Comment: Суметь хорошо задать вопрос, чтобы при этом сразу расхотелось помогать - это надо ухитриться... Ты читал, что вообще делает `File.Open`?

Comment: @Qwertiy Начнем с того, что до того как попробовать File.Open(), я попробовал с процессом. Не получилось и я решил попробовать однострочный File.Open(), чтобы избежать неловкой ситуации с ответом в одну строчку... Читайте пожалуйста весь вопрос, перед тем как оставлять такого рода комментарии...

Comment: @Philippe, я читал весь вопрос. Именно поэтому сказал _"Суметь **хорошо** задать вопрос, чтобы при этом сразу расхотелось помогать"_ - т. е. вопрос сам по себе хороший и оформлен хорошо, но именно такие моменты отбивают желание не него отвечать. Может, конечно, я один такой, но для меня это как флаг типа "если попытаешься ответить, то будет куча дополнительных вопросов чуть ли не по каждой строке ответа, а то и вообще не по нему". И с остальными факторами он в данном случае не сочетается, поэтому и оставил такой комментарий.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я поправил первый образец кода, так лучше?

Comment: prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; Пробовали ставить в true?

Comment: @eblomyac Пробовал, не сработало

Comment: @Philippe После того как вы "превратили" свой скрипт в исполняемый файл, удалось ли вам его запустить руками?